# Pesq numbers and clean speech comparison to processed speech

Tags: speech-processing, stft, speech

I am trying to evaluate my processed speech for my DSP project. My project is an implementation of an MMSE algorithm proposed by Y.Ephraim and D. Malah, "Speech Enhancement Using a Minimum Mean Square Error Short-Time Spectral Amplitude Estimator," in the IEEE Transactions on Acoustics, Speech, and Signal Processing, Vol. ASSP-32, No. 6, Dec. 1984.
As per project requirements, I ran PESQ, LLR, and segment SNR. I got numbers, but I am not sure what they mean. Is high number is good or bad? Also, what does it mean if I get a negative number?

Please help and thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Well, I submitted my project. Thanks to the help of this group.

As for the PESQ number, I think the range is between 1 and 5, where 5 being excellent and 1 is low.

Anyhow, I did another trick to estimate my performance. Instead of feeding the functions (SESQ, LLR, and Segment SNR) the clean speech and the processed speech, I fed them clean speech with the clean speech. I got numbers and these were my reference (or maximum) numbers. Then I compared all my runs against these reference numbers